# How to write JSON to HDFS partitioned by dates from Kafka by flume

Tags: json, hdfs, apache-kafka, flume

We have jsons in kafka like follows:
{'date':'2017-01-01','timestamp': 1483228800, 'field1':xxxx,...}. 
{'date':'2017-01-02','timestamp': 1483315200, 'field1':xxxx,...}. 
We want to load events to hdfs from kafka using flume. We hope the files are partitioned by date from the json. However, we don't know whether flume support this feature. It seems only httpsource support jsonhandler. I wonder whether kafka source has the same support.

Our configuration

```
a.sources = kafka1
a.channels = channel1
a.sinks = hdfs1
a.sources.kafka1.channel = channel1
a.sources.kafka1.type =  org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource

a.sources.kafka1.topic = topic1

a.channels.channel1.type = memory
a.sinks.hdfs1.type = hdfs
a.sinks.hdfs1.channel = channel1
a.sinks.hdfs1.path = maprfs:///user/abc/topic1/date=%{date}
a.sinks.hdfs1.fileType = SequenceFile
a.sinks.hdfs1.useLocalTimeStamp = false
```

As a result, the date is empty.  How to get the actual date value?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. Basically, we need to add regex interceptor to extract the date information and put it into 'flume header'.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your Kafka channel is populated by JSON objects, you can set your agent up as follows:

```
a.channels= kafka1
a.sinks = hdfs1

a.channels.kafka1.type = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
a.channels.kafka1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = hostnameorip:9092,hostnameorip:9092
a.channels.kafka1.kafka.topic = topic_sample
a.channels.kafka1.kafka.consumer.group.id = consumer_group_sample

a.sinks.hdfs1.type = hdfs
a.sinks.hdfs1.channel = kafka1
a.sinks.hdfs1.path = /user
a.sinks.hdfs1.fileType = SequenceFile
a.sinks.hdfs1.filePrefix = /abc/topic1/date=%{date}
```

I'm no expert on Flume, but you do not need to use a source if all you wish to do is pull events from Kafka and store in HDFS. You can pull fields from the JSON events to use in the filename by referencing the field names like this: %{field}

I hope this helps